# Google map loading but not showing

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I don't what's causing this issue, I am not able to see google mp even though it's loading.
jQuery is being loaded, bootstrap classes are also being loaded.

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=true&libraries=places,geometry&callback=initMap"></script>

<script>
function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 8,
    center: {lat: 14.5800, lng: 121.0000}
  });
}

</script>

<div id="map" style="height:450px;width:100%;"></div>
```

And this is how my map is being shown.
[image]

Comment: Did you check your javascript console for errors?

Answer (score 2):

I have experienced something similar, because i have the map on a button that shows and hide it(bootstrap collapse action). How i solved: Try Showing the map without any container, if this works, check the container of the map that are you using. 
It seems that the Google Maps Loading are affected by the "collapse" action of bootstrap. When i load the map without the collapse action it works, so the problem is that you have the map in "not active" or "not showing" status and the map doesn't load properly. 
My Function code of the Map:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);
function initMap(){
  var mapDiv = document.getElementById('map');
  var map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, {
    center: {lat: 4.619870, lng: -74.067577},
    zoom: 16});
    var mainmarker = new google.maps.Marker({ //Line 1
      position: {lat: 4.619870, lng: -74.067577}, //Line2: Location to be highlighted
      map: map,//Line 3: Reference to map object
      title: 'Casa de Bolsa', //Line 4: Title to be given
      icon : 'images/pin.png'
    });
    //console.log("map ready");
    return map;
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

seems simply a wrong order of the element 
try this way *( And check if sensor is effectively required.. )*

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
 <head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
  <title>PHP/MySQL & Google Maps Example</title>
</head>
<body>

<div id="map" style="height:450px;width:100%;"></div>

<script>
function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 8,
    center: {lat: 14.5800, lng: 121.0000}
  });
}

</script>

  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=true&libraries=places,geometry&callback=initMap"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>

<script>
function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 8,
    center: {lat: 14.5800, lng: 121.0000}
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);
</script>

<div id="map" style="height:450px;width:100%;"></div>
```

standard way ref-http://www.w3schools.com/googleapi/google_maps_basic.asp

Answer (score -1):

The script is defined before function so it can't find it. You can use async defer.

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=true&libraries=places,geometry&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
```

Comment: How about <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js..."
        async defer></script> ?

Comment: sorry, the libraries=places,geometry is actually the right way to ask for several libraries. The real problem is that script is defined before initMap() function so it can't find this function.